# turning positional servo motor more then 180 degrees

Tags: arduino-uno, servo

My RC servo motor is capable of turning more then 180 degrees(around 200 degrees) when I physically turn it, but when I use my code it only turns 180.

Is there a way to code it so that it turns to 200 instead of 180?

Comment: what code are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

First some basics to clear definitions:
A Servo Motor does not normally spin a full 360 degree rotation. Instead it is limited to a range of 180, 270 or 90 degrees depending on the make or type. A control signal is sent to the servo to position the shaft at the desired angle. 

**Conventional Servo Motor Timing**

In a conventional analog servo motor a PWM signal with a period of 20 ms is used to control the motors. A signal of 20 ms has a frequency of 50 Hz.

The width of the pulse is varied between 1 and 2 ms to control the motor shaft position.

- A pulse width of 1.5ms will cause the servo shaft to rest in the 90 degree position, the center of its travel.
- A pulse width of 1ms will cause the servo shaft to rest at the 0 degree position.
- A pulse width of 2ms will cause the servo shaft to rest in the 180 degree position.

Varying the pulse width between 1ms and 2ms will move the servo shaft through the full 180 degrees of its travel. You can bring it to rest at any angle you desire by adjusting the pulse width accordingly.

So if your servo is a 270 degree servo (like the domanrc DM-S0903MD or DS3218 270 Degree Digital RC Servo) the standard sweep sketch (Arduino Servo library) will let your servo sweep from 0-270 even if in the *.ino its `myservo.write(180);` So to simply test you could use `write(map(desired_angle, 0, 270, 0, 180))`
If you want to control it more precicly you use microseconds.

```
servo.attach(5,500,2500)
servo.writeMicroseconds(1500);
```

**AND** you have to use an extra power supply for 270 degree servos, the 5V from Arduino want make them move or only in a jittering way of.
If you just have a "defect" 180 degree servo turning to lets say 190 degree for some reason, you might try the microsecond method playing around with the values in attach, also use an extra power supply, but for real over 180 degree action get a 270 degree servo.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a servo can manually be turned more than 180 degrees doesn't mean that it *should* be turned more than 180 degrees.

Most servos will include a certain amount of leeway in their design to help reduce damage from external forces, but the internal design will be geared<sup>1</sup> towards operating over a 180 degree range.

While it may be possible to "overdrive" the motor by changing the PWM timing signals (see the [Servo attach() reference page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ServoAttach)) doing so may end up damaging the servo itself.

---

<sup>1: Pun intended</sup>